# Using the same condition in WHERE clause multiple times

Tags: sql, sql-server

What kind of implications would there be if the same condition was added multiple times in a WHERE clause?

```
SELECT * FROM Users
WHERE userName = 'Test' AND userName = 'Test' AND userName = 'Test'
```

Would there be performance issues with this? Or does the server remember the result of the condition and not execute it again and again and again?

Comment: why you need the same condition to add multiple times?

Comment: most probably the additional conditions will be ignored by query optimizer

Comment: Looks like you patch together your query in code at runtime. Don't do that. Maybe we can help you if you give use the bigger picture of your question.

Comment: I created a view and had mistakenly put the same condition multiple times there. So, I was wondering if there would be performance issues from that.

Comment: you can simply edit the view and remove the unnecessary condition

Comment: Just look at your execution plan. Most probably, the optimizer will use the predicate only once.

Comment: @Serg Exactly as you said, the duplicate conditions have all been removed from the predicate in the execution plan. Thanks!

Comment: SQL is a *declarative* language. *Logically* there is a single predicate in your `WHERE` clause, and so logically the system should only evaluate it once.